# Create form for examples. using 2 iframe. On the iframe “A” the source code php on iframe “B” the result

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I don't know how to ask exactly , but i want to do something similar the examples of w3school

Example

iframe a the source code PHP

iframe b the result of the code PHP on iframe A

If someone has some idea? thx

The final result must to be similar to https://www.w3schools.com/php/phptryit.asp?filename=tryphp_intro

Answer (score 0):

thx so much for the help.....before close post and now zero response.

Thx for all

Comment: It is just a bad question and not good fit for StackOverflow Q&A. Basically you are asking someone to do work for you for free.

Comment: Basically it's NOT true....i 've only question how to do the tag php by iframe  passing value from iframe to iframe , because i want to do something as final result similar to examples w3school..... I don't know you....but i work.... i don't ask to noone to work for me.